# onclick function does not get registered in created DOM element's outerHTML

Tags: javascript, events, properties, attributes, appendchild

I wonder why the onclick function for my button created by createElement("button") does not get registered and fired when I take use of the buttons outerHTML. I mean, a normal attribute like Title does get attached, but the function does not.

```
function createBtn(answer){
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    var btnTxt = document.createTextNode("Are we twins?");
    btn.appendChild(btnTxt);

    btn.onclick = function(){
        alert(answer);
    }
    btn.title = "This is the title";

    document.write(btn.outerHTML); // onclick is not registered
    document.body.appendChild(btn); // onclick is registered

}

createBtn("Not quite");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outerHTML property of a HTML Node returns `String`. The events will be attached to the HTML Node, but when you convert them to Stings all the events linked to them are lost. So, when you use `document.write` with `btn.outerHTML`, it copies the button as a text and all events attached are lost.

But when you use `appendChild` with `btn` object, it appends the HTMLButtonElement object with the events attached to it.

So, if you have to use `outerHTML`, attach the events once you write it to the document.

Comment: Aren't all attributes like .title, .style and .onclick all object values?

Comment: This is because of difference between event attribute and event property. when you say btn.onclick it adds an event handler property. The event properties are available in DOM Objects but not in the HTML itself. You can use btn.setAttribute() method to set 'onclick ' as an event attribute rather than event property (This is discouraged). For title, style both atribute and property are same. So when you add them as property it will update the attribute also. Please see the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c9hvpmsa/1/)

Comment: Very clearing, especially your second comment. Thank you!